# Header and detail record error handling in ssis

Tags: ssis

This is related to Dataflow task in SSIS.

I have developed a DFT to process a ragged flat file with header and detail records.

2 different tables to store header(Invoice_header) and  detail record(Invoice_lines).  These 2 tables are connected with Foreign key relationship and the primary keys are from header record.

All are working perfectly fine with script task and there are 2 flow of records, one for header and another for detail. 
Header record is first processed and loaded to Invoice_header table and then Invoice_line table is updated with detail record.  Now the problem is when there is primary key violation in Invoice_header table, the processing stops for header record but detail records are loaded successfully which is not expected.

My requirement is to stop the whole processing when there is any issue in updating the header record that has primary key violation or any issue for that matter.

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: **File Layout:**
----------------
HDR;SJCSYD;5999920;ACWFNTFLT;08/02/2017;AUD; 112483.26;0;0;
2020700242;SND;DT; 356.13;
2020700242;SND;TL; 194.00;
2020700489;SND;DT; 5503.35;
2020700489;SND;TL; 194.00;
HDR;SJCSYD;5999920;ACWFNTFPJ;08/02/2017;AUD; 1242.20;0;0;
6220704503;SND;TL; 83.00;
6220704920;SND;TL; 185.00;
6420700758;SND;TL; 185.00;
6420700761;SND;TL; 83.00;

**DFT:**
------
Flat file source --> Script task --> ole destination 1 for header record --> old destination 2 for detail record.

Answer (score 0):

The control flow allows [precedent constraints](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2006/10/30/using-constraints-and-expressions/).   Precedent constraints allow you to do things in steps.   The dataflow does not, it will start all things at once.

So, instead of one dataflow with two destinations, use two dataflows with one destination each.

[image]

Above, the top dataflow loads the header.  The bottom dataflow loads the detail rows.  If the top dataflow fails, the bottom dataflow will not start.  This solves your problem.

> Now the problem is when there is primary key violation in Invoice_header table, the processing stops for header record but detail records are loaded successfully which is not expected.

If Data Flow Task 1 (header) fails, then Data Flow Task 2 (details) will not start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Troy for your reply.  
Currently I have one script task which has 2 output flow. One for header and another for detail.  Do you mean I can have 2 script tasks, one each for header and detail.  In that way, will it fail the detail processing if any issue in processing header record.  Please note I also need some fields from header to populate detail record table.  Can i handle it somehow in one script task itself?

Comment: Yes. Use two script tasks.  One for header and one for details.  Place each script task in separate Data Flow Tasks.

Comment: Sounds like an idea.  I will try and let you know. Once again Thanks a lot for your reply Troy!